# Problem solving - Which will run out first?

Tags: problem-solving

I have a problem solving question I've been having difficulty wrapping my head around.

Let's say there are 5 different coal power stations

each uses up coal at a different rate

each has a different amount of coal reserve

each gets more coal shipped in a different rate.

Which will run out of coal first?

Comment: Are these the only facts we know about the stations?

Comment: A more specific question would help us to answer it.

Comment: Yes, you can put in arbitrary values for each in kilograms and kilograms per annum @NDewolf

Comment: @ThomasShemeld Are the rates constant over the time ?

Comment: Yes they are @callculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give an algebraic solution, complementing the geometric approach, assume each coal station has $c_0$ coal in the beginning and is supplied at rate $r_i$ while using at rate $r_u$. We assume $r_u > r_i$ otherwise they never run out of coal and can be eliminated from consideration.

Then,
$$
c_t = c_0 - (r_u - r_i) t,
$$
and so $$c_t = 0 \implies t = \frac{c_0}{r_u - r_i}.$$

This needs to be computed for each one, and the minimum one should be selected.

Comment: Many thanks. Does this class as a reccurence relation? @gt6989b

Comment: Your equation is not right. It should be $c_t=c_0-(\color{blue}{r_u-r_i})\cdot t$.

Comment: @callculus fixed, typo -- changed sign at the last second.

Comment: @ThomasShemeld this is not a recurrence

Comment: @gt6989b I´ve retracted my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

If you plot the amount of coal at each station as a function of time you will see straight lines (with negative slopes). See which one crossed the time axis first.

You can of course do this with simple algebra but the picture may be informative.